USB HUB gets disconnected
I have Pi Zero 2 W with an USB dongle. This dongle connects an external Wifi antenna and a mic to the Pi.
The problem is that the USB dongle gets disconnected after 5-30 minutes. Then I have to restart the Pi.
The Pi is powered by a 5V/8A unit.
Those are the last kernel logs. There are a lot FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost messages from the mic, followed by ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected and usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2.
Jul 07 20:50:43.475022 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 985 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:43.476998 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 987 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:43.576038 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1086 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:44.365001 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1875 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:44.676985 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 139 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:44.975942 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 438 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:45.763897 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1226 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:47.016789 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 431 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:51.386451 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 705 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:51.932397 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1251 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:52.391353 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1710 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:52.920321 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 191 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:53.044295 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 315 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:54.622205 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1893 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:57.058007 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 233 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:57.402974 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 578 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:57.692957 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 868 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:50:58.324886 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1500 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:54:58.637827 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 120 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:54:58.657628 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 142 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:54:59.697548 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1181 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:01.453477 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 890 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:01.462584 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 900 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:02.069709 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1505 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:02.161482 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1596 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:02.329480 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1764 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:02.453488 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1888 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:02.473497 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1910 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:05.615726 nistkasten kernel: dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm: 3 callbacks suppressed
Jul 07 20:55:05.616267 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 957 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:05.616674 nistkasten kernel: retire_capture_urb: 3 callbacks suppressed
Jul 07 20:55:07.681466 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 972 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:08.152661 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1446 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:12.209763 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1407 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:13.277762 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 427 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:13.979763 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1129 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:18.930808 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1984 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:21.924843 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 882 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:21.993797 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 951 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:23.978845 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 888 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:25.055858 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 1965 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:25.602827 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 464 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 20:55:25.891843 nistkasten kernel: Transfer to device 4 endpoint 0x2 frame 753 failed - FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost.
Jul 07 21:06:26.285602 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.287061 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.287327 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.287466 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.287853 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.288005 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.288114 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.288215 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.288313 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.288406 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.288507 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.288601 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.288728 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.288828 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.288926 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.289017 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.289094 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.289182 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.289671 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.289823 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.289925 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.290016 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.290113 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.290204 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.290294 nistkasten kernel:
Jul 07 21:06:26.290383 nistkasten kernel: ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:501: Not connected
Jul 07 21:06:26.290476 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jul 07 21:06:26.297253 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
Jul 07 21:06:26.305491 nistkasten kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from 98:9b:cb:5f:fa:bb by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jul 07 21:06:26.585503 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jul 07 21:06:26.921497 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 0
Jul 07 21:06:27.509474 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jul 07 21:06:27.649511 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 2
Jul 07 21:06:27.789476 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 3
Jul 07 21:06:27.929472 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 0
Jul 07 21:06:28.069482 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: timed out to flush queue 1
Jul 07 21:06:28.261552 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
Jul 07 21:06:28.445608 nistkasten kernel: Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
Jul 07 21:06:28.633641 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
Jul 07 21:06:28.634358 nistkasten kernel: Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
Jul 07 21:06:28.841491 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2148, idProduct=7022, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jul 07 21:06:28.843138 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
Jul 07 21:06:28.845144 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 HUB
Jul 07 21:06:28.846988 nistkasten kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 07 21:06:28.852399 nistkasten kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
Jul 07 21:06:29.137607 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Jul 07 21:06:29.237712 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0138, bcdDevice= 2.10
Jul 07 21:06:29.240462 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul 07 21:06:29.250599 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Jul 07 21:06:29.252325 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Jul 07 21:06:29.254589 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 123456
Jul 07 21:06:29.256526 nistkasten kernel: Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 0000000000000004
Jul 07 21:06:29.257589 nistkasten kernel: Mem abort info:
Jul 07 21:06:31.157364 nistkasten kernel:   ESR = 0x0000000096000005
Jul 07 21:06:31.202326 nistkasten kernel:   EC = 0x25: DABT (current EL), IL = 32 bits
Jul 07 21:06:31.249155 nistkasten kernel:   SET = 0, FnV = 0
Jul 07 21:06:31.294350 nistkasten kernel:   EA = 0, S1PTW = 0
Jul 07 21:06:31.351453 nistkasten kernel:   FSC = 0x05: level 1 translation fault
Jul 07 21:06:31.390615 nistkasten kernel: Data abort info:
Jul 07 21:06:31.406638 nistkasten kernel:   ISV = 0, ISS = 0x00000005, ISS2 = 0x00000000
Jul 07 21:06:31.425278 nistkasten kernel:   CM = 0, WnR = 0, TnD = 0, TagAccess = 0
Jul 07 21:06:31.442213 nistkasten kernel:   GCS = 0, Overlay = 0, DirtyBit = 0, Xs = 0
Jul 07 21:06:31.459839 nistkasten kernel: user pgtable: 4k pages, 39-bit VAs, pgdp=000000001ba41000
Jul 07 21:06:31.483887 nistkasten kernel: [0000000000000004] pgd=0000000000000000, p4d=0000000000000000, pud=0000000000000000
Jul 07 21:06:31.500829 nistkasten kernel: Internal error: Oops: 0000000096000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
Jul 07 21:06:31.517603 nistkasten kernel: Modules linked in: ctr ccm xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo >
Jul 07 21:06:31.554765 nistkasten kernel:  drm_panel_orientation_quirks backlight ip_tables x_tables ipv6 i2c_mux_pinctrl i2c_mux i2c_bcm2835
Jul 07 21:06:31.555005 nistkasten kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 240 Comm: kworker/u8:1 Tainted: G         C         6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1  Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1
Jul 07 21:06:31.555121 nistkasten kernel: Hardware name: Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W Rev 1.0 (DT)
Jul 07 21:06:31.555227 nistkasten kernel: Workqueue: rtw88_usb: rx wq rtw_usb_rx_handler [rtw88_usb]
Jul 07 21:06:31.555340 nistkasten kernel: pstate: 20000005 (nzCv daif -PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
Jul 07 21:06:31.555452 nistkasten kernel: pc : rtw_rx_fill_rx_status+0x54/0x298 [rtw88_core]
Jul 07 21:06:31.555559 nistkasten kernel: lr : rtw8822b_query_rx_desc+0x120/0x360 [rtw88_8822b]
Jul 07 21:06:31.555673 nistkasten kernel: sp : ffffffc080703c00
Jul 07 21:06:31.555822 nistkasten kernel: x29: ffffffc080703c00 x28: 0000000000000000 x27: 0000000000000000
Jul 07 21:06:31.555948 nistkasten kernel: x26: ffffff8001d08028 x25: 0000000000000018 x24: ffffff80097d0018
Jul 07 21:06:31.556052 nistkasten kernel: x23: ffffff8003daa000 x22: ffffff80097d0038 x21: ffffff8003daa000
Jul 07 21:06:31.556168 nistkasten kernel: x20: ffffffc080703d58 x19: ffffffc080703d28 x18: 0000000000000014
Jul 07 21:06:31.556277 nistkasten kernel: x17: 00000000a22da961 x16: ffffffed478cbfc0 x15: 0000000000000000
Jul 07 21:06:31.556383 nistkasten kernel: x14: 0144aad1bd2521b8 x13: ffffffed4793cbb0 x12: 00000000fa83b2da
Jul 07 21:06:31.556494 nistkasten kernel: x11: 0000000000000332 x10: 0000000000001a30 x9 : ffffffecfd09d7e0
Jul 07 21:06:31.556606 nistkasten kernel: x8 : 000000000000001c x7 : ffffffecfceedcd8 x6 : 000000000000031a
Jul 07 21:06:31.556730 nistkasten kernel: x5 : 0000000000000004 x4 : 0000000000000000 x3 : ffffff8003da88c0
Jul 07 21:06:31.556842 nistkasten kernel: x2 : ffffff80097d0038 x1 : 0000000000000000 x0 : 0000000000000000
Jul 07 21:06:31.556953 nistkasten kernel: Call trace:
Jul 07 21:06:31.557059 nistkasten kernel:  rtw_rx_fill_rx_status+0x54/0x298 [rtw88_core]
Jul 07 21:06:31.557195 nistkasten kernel:  rtw8822b_query_rx_desc+0x120/0x360 [rtw88_8822b]
Jul 07 21:06:31.557302 nistkasten kernel:  rtw_usb_rx_handler+0xec/0x190 [rtw88_usb]
Jul 07 21:06:31.557412 nistkasten kernel:  process_one_work+0x148/0x3b8
Jul 07 21:06:31.557668 nistkasten kernel:  worker_thread+0x32c/0x450
Jul 07 21:06:31.557780 nistkasten kernel:  kthread+0x11c/0x128
Jul 07 21:06:31.557885 nistkasten kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x20
Jul 07 21:06:31.557989 nistkasten kernel: Code: a9017e7f a9027e7f 79403a60 f9400c61 (b9400421)
Jul 07 21:06:31.558330 nistkasten kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Jul 07 21:06:31.641619 nistkasten kernel: rtw_8822bu 1-1.2:1.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
Jul 07 21:06:31.643815 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Jul 07 21:06:31.644852 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=08bb, idProduct=2902, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jul 07 21:06:31.645835 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 07 21:06:31.646777 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: Product: USB PnP Sound Device
Jul 07 21:06:31.647876 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: C-Media Electronics Inc.
Jul 07 21:06:31.649046 nistkasten kernel: input: C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.2/0003:08BB:2902.0002/input/input3
Jul 07 21:06:31.649191 nistkasten kernel: hid-generic 0003:08BB:2902.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [C-Media Electronics Inc.       USB PnP Sound Device] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input2
Jul 07 21:38:33.521531 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Jul 07 21:39:16.577582 nistkasten kernel: usb 1-1.4: reset full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
lines 645-667/667 (END)


Those are the logs from lsusb -v:
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 08bb:2902 Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x08bb Texas Instruments
  idProduct          0x2902 PCM2902 Audio Codec
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 C-Media Electronics Inc.
  iProduct                2 USB PnP Sound Device
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0099
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength       0x0037
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr(0)        1
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             1
        wChannelConfig     0x0001
          Left Front (L)
        iChannelNames           0
        iTerminal               0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             7
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               8
        iTerminal               0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (SELECTOR_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 8
        bNrInPins               1
        baSourceID(0)          10
        iSelector               0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                10
        bSourceID               2
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x43
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
          Automatic Gain Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x00
        iFeature                0
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                13
        bSourceID               2
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls(0)       0x03
          Mute Control
          Volume Control
        bmaControls(1)       0x00
        iFeature                0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           7
        bDelay                  1 frames
        wFormatTag         0x0001 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                14
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             1
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            2 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        48000
        tSamFreq[ 1]        44100
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            9
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Adaptive
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0064  1x 100 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioStreaming Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay         0x0000
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      60
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval               2

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0138 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.10
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x2357 TP-Link
  idProduct          0x0138
  bcdDevice            2.10
  iManufacturer           1 Realtek
  iProduct                2 802.11ac NIC
  iSerial                 3 123456
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0035
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           5
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x05  EP 5 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x08  EP 8 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
...

The Pi acts as a surveillance system. It has also a Camera Module 3, an infrared sensor and two infrared LEDs. The LEDs are powered directly by the power supply.
So does anybody has an idea why the USB dongle gets always disconnected?
Edit 1
I have the feeling the Pi crashes more often when its hot outside. vcgencmd measure_temp print 65 °C right now and I cant even work 2 minutes over SSH with the Pi.
Edit 2
When the external Wifi antenna is disconnected then there are no FIQ reported NYET. Data may have been lost. messages.

That PSU is a LED driver. You should make sure that the power supplied to your RPi isn't too full of noise/ripple. Some LED drivers could have a lot less output filtering than mobile chargers or regular RPi PSUs.

Are you sure? I thought LED driver were exactly build for this job. Btw this driver was running a Pi Zero W without problems for about 2 years continuously. Are there any logs when undervoltage happens? There are no results with dmesg | grep -iC 3 "under-voltage detected
`

Ripple or noisy power output oes NOT mean undervoltage..

It was indeed a problem with the power supply. A jumper wire had a loose connection. Since I replaced the cable, i have had no more crashes.
